# Arduino Serial Communication from Java

Tags: java, arduino, serial-communication, rxtx, jarduino

I can't serial the port JAVA to Arduino .. 
I Get this error

Load RxTx
Windows 10

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while
>
> loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in
>
> java.library.path
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>
> at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.(CommPortIdentifier.java:123)
>
> at org.sintef.jarduino.comm.Serial4JArduino.connect(Serial4JArduino.java:88)
>
> at org.sintef.jarduino.comm.Serial4JArduino.(Serial4JArduino.java:82)
>
> at org.sintef.jarduino.AbstractJArduino.(AbstractJArduino.java:30)
>
> at org.sintef.jarduino.JArduino.(JArduino.java:45)
>
> at Arduino.ArduinoServer.(ArduinoServer.java:25)
>
> at Arduino.ArduinoServer.main(ArduinoServer.java:37)

**JAVA CODE**

```
package Arduino;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.sintef.jarduino.DigitalPin;
import org.sintef.jarduino.DigitalState;
import org.sintef.jarduino.JArduino;
import org.sintef.jarduino.PinMode;

    public class ArduinoServer  extends JArduino{

        public ArduinoServer(String port) {
            super(port);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        static int LedParlakligi=0;
        public static void main(String[] Args)
        {

            String serialPort;

            serialPort = "1";

        JArduino arduino = new ArduinoServer(serialPort);
        arduino.runArduinoProcess();


        }
        @Override
        protected void loop() {

            digitalWrite(DigitalPin.PIN_9, DigitalState.fromValue((byte)10));
            delay(50); // wait for a second

        }
        @Override
        protected void setup() {
            // initialize the digital pin as an output.
            // Pin 13 has an LED connected on most Arduino boards:
            pinMode(DigitalPin.PIN_9, PinMode.OUTPUT);

        }


    }
```

**MY Libraries all** 
[Libraires](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5vrd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have have the native library installed on your machine: http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download

Link to it in Eclipse:
Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> RXTXcomm -> Native library location

Comment: It didnt work. I am going to download rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2 and select native library location to this folder . But i get some issue again..